# CommunicationException in processing Array function

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am testing interaction between server and client app on single desktop and having issue with processing Array. My interface looks next

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IMyService
    <OperationContract>
    Function GetData() As Array   
End Interface
```

Server side implementation, is next

```
Public Function GetData() As Array Implements IMyService.GetData
    Return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
End Function
```

Client side code, is next

```
Shared Function GetData() As Array
    Dim channel As IMyService = Nothing
    Try
        channel = ChannelFactory(Of IMyService).CreateChannel(New NetTcpBinding, address)
        Return channel.GetData()
    Finally
        If channel IsNot Nothing Then
            CType(channel, IClientChannel).Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

I am getting next exception upon executing **Return channel.GetData()**, and I don't have an issue with other interface functions that returns simple types (double, integer, etc.). My server app is [self hosting WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx).

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9270000'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:

        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)

        InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
             ErrorCode=10054
             HResult=-2147467259
             Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
             NativeErrorCode=10054
             Source=System
             StackTrace:
                  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
             InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use List(Of Integer) type instead of array. It seems it's untyped (unfortunately, I am not vb dev.)

Or set a ServiceKnownType attribute:

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IMyService

    <OperationContract>
    <ServiceKnownType(GetType(Integer()))>
    Function GetData() As Array
End Interface
```

By the way to simplify the process of investigating WCF issue it's useful to add error handling:

[Error handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx)

For you case it's exception: Type 'System.Int32[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfint:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.